# OutOfMemoryException with Apache ObJectRelationalBridge

Tags: java, sybase, ojb

I'm facing an OutOfMemoryException when trying to load a list of objects using OJB persistence broker.
There are more than 20000 objects in the database (sybase).
I have tried to limit the size of the returned list to 200. But the problem persists.
Since OJB do not support paging, is there any solution to resolve this problem ?

```
PersistenceBroker broker= BrokerFactory.getBroker();
QueryByCriteria query =  new QueryByCriteria( Fo.class, criteria);
query.setEndAtIndex(200);
Collection listFo= broker.getCollectionByQuery(query);
```

Comment: Does `Fo` have relationships with other classes? Could you possibly be pulling a large number of other objects into memory?

Comment: Yes, Fo have many relationships with other classes. I can't change the current model architecture. So I'm wondering if I can do something like pagination or limiting the size of the returned list.

Comment: There's usually some way with these frameworks to avoid pulling in relationships you don't need. Not familiar with this one in particular so can't tell you exactly how to do it.